# ruby shortcut for this?

Tags: ruby

I have this, which will have another 3 or 4 variables appended:

```
name, theme = row[0], row[1]
```

Is there a shortcut to the code on the right? I tried:

```
name, theme = row
```

But then name returned the entire row, and didn't seem to work in this case.

I am using CSV.foreach, and the above didn't work when I added {headers: true}:

```
CSV.foreach('file.csv', {headers: true}) do |row|
  name, theme = row

  name # returns entire row in string
end
```

Comment: are you sure? which ruby version you use?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've updated my answer as to why.

Comment: Obviously, in your case, row is not true array.

Comment: Yes, OBVIOUSLY! I wonder why I am even asking this question if it so obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case your row is not array, try calling

```
name, theme = Array row
```

or

```
name, theme = row.to_a
```

If it doesn't have to_a method, yo've to define it.

Answer (score 3):

`name, theme = row` is ok.

```
irb(main):001:0> row = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> first,second = row
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):003:0> first
=> 1
irb(main):004:0> second
=> 2
```

Comment: Just updated my answer as to why it might not be working for me.